# Large media uploads to azure blob service for authenticated users

Tags: django, azure, cloud, azure-blob-storage, blob

I am new to azure and attempting to create a REST API that uploads large media files (4gb) to azure blob service. I'm using Django to create the API. The API should only allow authenticated users to upload files. I would like the upload to be handled by the front end because I am running my Django instance in a container on Azure and would like to reduce memory / compute load on it to reduce cost. I was wondering if I could dynamically generate a time-sensitive token that is sent to the front end to allow users to upload directly to my Azure blob instance. Is it practical to generate a new SAS token for every authenticated upload? Any suggestions on how I can achieve this in a production-safe manner?

Thanks!

Comment: How are your users authenticated? Are you using Azure AD for authentication/authorization?

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for your reply. Users are authenticated using Django. Permissions are stored in the session state and API requests are authenticated by checking these permissions.

Comment: Shared Access Signature is the way to go. You could create SAS tokens in the backend and send it to frontend and use that to upload files into blob storage directly. However please note that your users can potentially share the SAS tokens with other users and they will be able to upload blobs.

Comment: @gauravMantri Ok excellent. I will go with the SAS token approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. Yes, you can generate a SAS token to your authenticated users, and you can also specify a safe duration for it, like 30 minutes for example.

[You can see how to do this in this paper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-python).

You'll find on the *Getting Started* section the sample that dynamically generates the SAS token and uses it to access the Blob Storage.

Comment: While there are a lot of words here, **this ultimately boils down to a link-only answer**. On Stack Overflow, answers should be self-contained. Answers may _include_ links, but the links should be to provide additional details, not relied upon to answer the question. Please [edit] your answer to include additional details and, ideally, sample code.

Comment: Further, I've seen a _lot_ of answers starting with this line. **On Stack Overflow, we try to keep answers focused, without distracting information.** It's fine to introduce that you're from the Founders Hub team as that's relevant to your expertise. But there's no need to include your name in the introduction or signature since it doesn't help answer the question. (And, besides, it's also in your user name.) Further, there isn't much benefit to adding the disclaimer that you may not be able to follow-up; ideally you do, but that's always an understood risk. Can you pass this onto your team?